# Получить данные из ответа на GET запрос

Tags: c#, wpf, http, get

привет есть код. Я отправляю запрос и в ответ получаю файл. а как мне его  получить из массива байтов 
например задать как источник данных для mediaelement

```
request(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://cdn.kinoprofi.org/files/4KUyL0E1SmSv1SmHSRbZw,1492779714/Dark.Places.2015.HDRip.flv");
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.GetResponseStream().ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[HttpWebResponse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse(v=vs.110).aspx) устаревший метод. Вместо него лучше использовать [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) и его сопутствующие классы HttpResponseMessage и HttpRequestMessage. Получится что-то вроде такого:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri("твой_url"),
        Method = HttpMethod.Get
    };
    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);

    using (var stream = File.Create("C:\tempFile"))
    {
        await response.Content.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }
}
```