# Как передать переменную через GET запрос

Tags: c#, get

Господа, помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Нужно из программы на C# передать переменную в браузерную строку таким образом: http://localhost/Projects/buttons/gett.php?cab=19, собственно, 19 - это значение, которое должно быть передано из программы. Всем большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

```
int varmy = 19;
string url = "http://localhost/Projects/buttons/gett.php?cab=" + varmy.ToString();    
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);    
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();    
var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Другие варианты [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post)

Ещё вариант:

```
private static string GET(string Url, string Data)
{
    System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Url + "?" + Data);
    System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    System.IO.Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
    string Out = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
    return Out;
}

Answer = GET("http://localhost/Projects/buttons/gett.php", "cab=19");
```

Answer (score 2):

Для создания сложного URI лучше использовать [UriBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.uribuilder(v=vs.110).aspx). В вашем случае будет следующий код:

```
var builder = new UriBuilder("http://localhost")
{
    Path = "/Projects/buttons/gett.php",
    Query = "cab=19"
};
var uri = builder.Uri;
```

А далее воспользоваться классом HttpClient и HttpRequestMessage для запроса, как я [писал ранее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/656240/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-get-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81/656264#656264).

Для наглядности понимания что есть что в URI ниже приведена иллюстрация.

```
foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
\_/   \_________/ \__/\_________/\__________/ \__/
 |         |        |     |           |        |
scheme    host     port  path       query   fragment
```